# Что значит void 0?

Tags: javascript, операторы, javascript-faq

Иногда вижу такие ссылки

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Войти</a>
```

и `void 0` тоже используется в библиотеке [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), например:

```
if (obj == null) return void 0;
```

Что значит `void 0`, и для чего оно нужно?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Оператор `void`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)[<sup>[спецификация]</sup>](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.4.2) вычисляет переданное выражение и всегда возвращает `undefined`.

**Примеры:**

```
void 0          // возвращает undefined
void(0)         // это тоже возвращает undefined
void "привет"   // тоже возвращает undefined
void new Date() // всегда возвращает undefined
```

### Зачем этот оператор вообще нужен?

Если `void 0` всегда возвращает `undefined`, можно просто использовать `undefined`, разве нет?

Можно. На самом деле, `void` не очень полезный оператор, и я его использую очень редко. Но он пригодится в некоторых ситуациях:

- В старых браузерах (я не уверен в каких именно. По-моему, в IE 6 и ниже и в Netscape) была возможность изменить значение `undefined`:

  ```
  undefined = 5;   // в старых браузерах изменит значение undefined,
                   // в новых ничего не делает
  5 === undefined; // true в старых браузерах, false в новых
  ```

  Не всегда известно, что `undefined` значит `undefined`. Поэтому некоторые библиотеки используют `void 0`.
- Даже в новых браузерах `undefined` - допустимое имя переменной внутри функции:

  ```
  function f() {
    var undefined = 5;
    return undefined;
  }
  f(); // возвращает 5
  ```

  Но если вы пишете такой код, это ваша вина.
- Если хотите сохранить свою энергию: `void 0` на три символа короче `undefined`. Хотя `0[0]` еще короче.

Ссылка, начинающаяся с `javascript:`, обычно отправляет пользователя на страницу с текстом, который код возвращает. Например:

```html
Нажимай <a href="javascript: 'Привет!'">СЮДА</a>!
```

Но если вы хотите, чтобы ссылка никуда не отправляла пользователя, надо как-то вернуть `undefined`. Традиционно люди используют `void(0)`, но `undefined` и другие варианты тоже работают.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Войти</a>
```

### Почему именно `void 0`?

Это только традиция; `void 0` - простой и короткий код. Другие варианты, такие как `void 9` и `void "привет"`, тоже работают.