# Регистрация на сайте в Опера 49.0 пишет javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Не могу завершить регистрацию на сайте. При нажатии "завершить" регистрацию с лева внизу появляется надпись javascript:void(0)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  javascript в браузере Опера включен в настройках. В чем причина. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит void 0?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434114/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-void-0)

Comment: Префикс `javascript:` говорит обработать ссылку как js, `void` - ничего не делающий оператор, который возвращает `undefined` (остатки истории). Т. е. кнопка ничего не делает, а обработчик формы, вероятно, висит на событии `submit`.

Comment: Значит дело не javascript:void(0)