# Что делает оператор void?

Tags: javascript

> Этот оператор позволяет вставлять выражения, которые производят дополнительные действия, в места, где ожидается undefined.
>
> Оператор void часто используется для получения примитивного значения undefined, используя "void(0)" (что эквивалентно "void 0"). В подобных случаях можно просто использовать глобальную переменную undefined (предполагая, что её значение по умолчанию не было изменено).

Это что нам [говорит](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) по этому поводу MDN.

Что значит "в места, где ожидается `undefined`"? В чем отличие простого `void` от `void 0` (`void(0)`)?

"В подобных случаях можно просто использовать глобальную переменную undefined (предполагая, что её значение по умолчанию не было изменено)" - тогда почему

```
void function(){}();
```

работает, а

```
undefined function(){}();
```

нет?

Кроме того, разве глобальные `undefined`, `NaN`, `Infinity` и `null` не являются иммутабельными, что "их значение по умолчанию может быть изменено"?

Comment: Вообще, судя по всему, ассоциация: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434114/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-void-0?rq=1. Сразу не заметил, к сожалению...